# Проблема с синхронизацией в самописном SMTP-сервере

Tags: c#, многопоточность, smtp

Я написал СМТП-сервер, где каждый новый клиент работает с отдельным потоком, т.е.:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    SmtpHelper s = new SmtpHelper(this);

    Thread listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Listen));
    listen.Start();
}
```

Далее:

```
public void Listen()
{
    SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port); 
    SMTP_Listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();                

        _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();

        Thread newClient = new Thread(StartProcessing);

        l.Write("Создан поток для обработки клиента " + _sessionId);
        UserSessionController.AddSession( Convert.ToInt32(_sessionId));

        newClient.Name = _sessionId;
        newClient.IsBackground = true; // ???
        newClient.Start();
    }
}
```

Модуль работы с командами клиента

```
void StartProcessing()
{
    try
    {
        string namethread = "";

        try
        {
            namethread = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            l.Write("ошибка определения имени текущего потока: " + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }

        l.Write("текущий поток: " + namethread, namethread); 

        m_ConnectedIp = ParseIP_from_EndPoint(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
        m_ConnectedHostName = GetHostName(m_ConnectedIp);

        _email.ip = m_ConnectedIp;
        _email.port = 25;

        SendData("220 " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + " Service ready\r\n");

        //РАБОТА С ВХОДНЫМИ ДАННЫМИ
        while (true)
        {
            //если есть данные, то считаем их
            if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                //ТУТ МЫ ПОЛУЧАЕМ КЛИЕНТСКУЮ КОМАНДУ
                string lastCmd = ReadLine();

                if (lastCmd.Trim() == String.Empty)
                {
                    l.Write("Empty commmand (lastCmd)]", namethread);
                }
                else
                {
                    l.Write("lastCmd: " + lastCmd, namethread);    
                }

                //парсим команду
                if (lastCmd.Trim() != String.Empty)
                    ProceedCommand(lastCmd, namethread);
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        l.Write("SMTP StartProcessing Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }            
}
```

**Ошибка проявляется** вот в чем:

**Когда с сервером работают два или более клиента, то их команды (напр. HELLO, EHLO, QUIT  и пр.) могут сливаться, например, вместо команд HELO 111 и HELO 222 от двух клиентом могут мне прийти HL1 и  EOHL222.
Может все дело в модуле приема команд от клиента?**

Модуль приема команд от клиента:

```
private string ReadLine()
{
    try
    {
        long lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        ArrayList lineBuf = new ArrayList();
        byte prevByte = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (clientSocket == null)
                l.Write(" !!! clientSocket is NULL");

            if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                l.Write(" !!! сокет не включен!");

            if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                // Read next byte
                byte[] currByte = new byte[1];
                int countRecieved = clientSocket.Receive(currByte, 1, SocketFlags.None);

                // Count must be equal. Eg. some computers won't give byte at first read attempt
                if (countRecieved == 1)
                {
                    lineBuf.Add(currByte[0]);

                    // Line found
                    if ((prevByte == (byte)'\r' && currByte[0] == (byte)'\n'))
                    {
                        byte[] retVal = new byte[lineBuf.Count - 2];    // Remove <CRLF> 
                        lineBuf.CopyTo(0, retVal, 0, lineBuf.Count - 2);

                        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(retVal).Trim();
                    }

                    // Store byte
                    prevByte = currByte[0];

                    // reset last data time
                    lastDataTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //---- Time out stuff -----------------------//
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks > lastDataTime + ((long)(60000)) * 10000)
                {
                    l.Write("ERROR: Read timeout: " + (((long)(60000)) * 10000).ToString());

                    //clientSocket.Close();
                    l.Write("Сокет закрыт из-за простоя в " + (((long)(60000)) * 10000).ToString() + " м-сек.");

                    return ""; // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }    
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        l.Write("EROR ReadLine(): " + x.ToString());
        throw new Exception( x.Message);
    }
}
```